# xUnit - Display test names for theory memberdata (TestCase)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, xunit

I've been using NUnit for testing and I'm really fond of test cases. In NUnit you can easily set each test name in the test case using the SetName function in a TestCaseData class.

Does xUnit have a similar function for this?

Currently I can only see one test in the test explorer even tho I have 6 tests in the test case.

**xUnit test**

```
public class LogHandler : TestBase
{
    private ILogger _logger;

    public LogHandler()
    {
        //Arrange
        LogAppSettings logAppSettings = GetAppSettings<LogAppSettings>("Log");

        IOptions<LogAppSettings> options = Options.Create(logAppSettings);

        LogService logService = new LogService(new Mock<IIdentityService>().Object, options);

        LogProvider logProvider = new LogProvider(logService);

        _logger = logProvider.CreateLogger(null);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestCases => new[]
    {
        new object[] { LogLevel.Critical,
            new EventId(),
            new Exception(),
            1 },
        new object[] { LogLevel.Error,
            new EventId(),
            new Exception(),
            1 },
        new object[] { LogLevel.Warning,
            new EventId(),
            new Exception(),
            0 },
        new object[] { LogLevel.Information,
            new EventId(),
            new Exception(),
            0 },
        new object[] { LogLevel.Debug,
            new EventId(),
            new Exception(),
            0 },
        new object[] { LogLevel.Trace,
            new EventId(),
            new Exception(),
            0 },
        new object[] { LogLevel.None,
            new EventId(),
            new Exception(),
            0 }
    };

    [Theory, MemberData(nameof(TestCases))]
    public void Test(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, Exception exception, int count)
    {
        //Act
        _logger.Log<object>(logLevel, eventId, null, exception, null);

        //Assert
        int exceptionCount = Database.Exception.Count();

        Assert.Equal(exceptionCount, count);
    }
}
```

**xUnit test window**

[image]

Should be 6 tests here instead of one! (ignore GetOrganisationStatuses).

**NUnit test case**

```
public static IEnumerable TestDatabaseCases
{
    get
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData(LogLevel.Critical,
            new EventId(1),
            new Exception("Exception"),
            0,
            1).SetName("InsertException_Should_Insert_When_LogLevel_Critical");

        yield return new TestCaseData(LogLevel.Error,
            new EventId(1),
            new Exception("Exception"),
            0,
            1).SetName("InsertException_Should_Insert_When_LogLevel_Error");

        yield return new TestCaseData(LogLevel.Warning,
            new EventId(1),
            new Exception("Exception"),
            0,
            0).SetName("InsertException_Should_Not_Insert_When_LogLevel_Warning");

        yield return new TestCaseData(LogLevel.Information,
            new EventId(1),
            new Exception("Exception"),
            0,
            0).SetName("InsertException_Should_Not_Insert_When_LogLevel_Information");

        yield return new TestCaseData(LogLevel.Debug,
            new EventId(1),
            new Exception("Exception"),
            0,
            0).SetName("InsertException_Should_Not_Insert_When_LogLevel_Debug");
    }
}
```

**NUnit test window**

[image]

This is what I want in xUnit!

**How do I in xUnit set a name for each test in the test case?**

Comment: I had the same problem before. You class will need to inherit from IXunitSerializable. It's quite cumbersome to implement.. Not sure if there is a better method.

Comment: There is a ready to use implementation which bypasses a need to change code under test and test code. Simply include new custom xUnit TheoryAttribute, XunitDiscoverer class and two test classes - see second answer for details and MIT licensed working code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *Currently I can only see one test in the test explorer even tho I have 6 tests in the test case.*

This is because your test data is not considered serializable by xUnit.net. See this issue: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1473

The salient details are:

> ### The short answer
>
> If some of your theory data can't be "serialized" by xUnit.net, then
> it cannot be encapsulated into the serialization of a test case which
> we're required to do for the Visual Studio test runner.
>
> ### The long answer
>
> In the Visual Studio test runner, test cases are discovered in one
> process, and executed in another. Therefore, test cases must be able
> to be turned into an unqualified string representation (aka,
> "serialized") in order to be run. We can also serialize at the test
> method level, because that just involves knowing the type and method
> name (both strings). When you start putting data into the mix, we need
> to ensure we know how to serialize that data; if we can't serialize
> ***all*** of the data for a theory, then we have to fall back to just a single method (which we know we can serialize).

The full answer contains more detail.

> *In NUnit you can easily set each test name in the test case using the SetName function in a TestCaseData class.*
>
> *Does xUnit have a similar function for this?*

Not at this time.

Comment: That's a shame.. As it stands now I'll continue with NUnit. Hopefully they will fix this.

Comment: @Reft Common it's not a shame but small limitation which can be easily compensated for by small piece of code - see below for my answer. Anyway xUnit is a test framework of choice for large number of most important in DotNet world repos.

Comment: @JacekBlaszczynski Can you comment on what those reasons might be?

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

```
public class TestScenario
{
...
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Role: {Role}...";
    }
}
```

```
    [Theory]
    [ClassData(typeof(MyProvider))]
    public void TestScenarios(TestScenario scenaro)
    {
        TestScenarioInternal(scenaro);

    }
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: What is a relation between MyProvider and TestScenario classes?

Comment: @Dima, I believe MyProvider returns list of TestScenario instances.

Answer (score 8):

One readable and short way to do it would be:

```cs
public record AddNumbersTestCase(
    int Number1,
    int Number2,
    int ExpectedResult)
{
    private static readonly AddNumbersTestCase[] TestCases =
    {
        new(0, 0, 0),
        new(0, 1, 1),
        new(1, 0, 1),
        new(1, 1, 2),
        new(2, 3, 5),
    };

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestCasesData =>
        TestCases.Select(testCase => new object[] { testCase });

    public override string ToString() =>
        $"{Number1} + {Number2} should equal {ExpectedResult}";
}
```

```cs
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(AddNumbersTestCase.TestCasesData), MemberType = typeof(AddNumbersTestCase))]
public void FindDayOfWeek(AddNumbersTestCase testCase)
{
    int result = testCase.Number1 + testCase.Number2;

    Assert.Equal(testCase.ExpectedResult, result);
}
```

Comment: This is a nice workaround without too much plumbing!

Comment: This looks very nice, but it seems like xUnit doesn't know how to serialize the custom record type, and thus it displays only one test case, and outputs multiple results in this one test case. The output uses overridden `ToString()`, so it looks pretty there, but still doesn't resolve the initial question. Or am I missing something?

Comment: probably related to issue stated by Dasha: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1473

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is a working solution requiring some plumbing code which should work with unchanged tests. It requires implementation of custom TheoryAttribute, custom TheoryDiscoverer, and custom TestCase classes. Whole solution is available under MIT license in this repo [DjvuNet/DjvuNet.Shared.Tests](https://github.com/DjvuNet/DjvuNet/tree/master/DjvuNet.Shared.Tests/xunit).

Required files with implementations are:
[DjvuTheoryAttribute](https://github.com/DjvuNet/DjvuNet/blob/master/DjvuNet.Shared.Tests/xunit/DjvuTheoryAttribute.cs), [DjvuTheoryDiscoverer](https://github.com/DjvuNet/DjvuNet/blob/master/DjvuNet.Shared.Tests/xunit/DjvuTheoryDiscoverer.cs), [DjvuNamedDataRowTestCase](https://github.com/DjvuNet/DjvuNet/blob/master/DjvuNet.Shared.Tests/xunit/DjvuNamedDataRowTestCase.cs), [DjvuDataRowTestCase](https://github.com/DjvuNet/DjvuNet/blob/master/DjvuNet.Shared.Tests/xunit/DjvuDataRowTestCase.cs)

Usage is straightforward: compile above files either including them directly into test assembly or as a separate assembly and use them in code as [follows](https://github.com/DjvuNet/DjvuNet/blob/3d40c36830308c5b26bc6d08bd4568da5772def5/DjvuNet.Tests/DataChunks/DirmChunkTests.cs#L54):

```
    [DjvuTheory]
    [ClassData(typeof(DjvuJsonDataSource))]
    public void DirmChunk_Theory(DjvuJsonDocument doc, int index)
    {
        int pageCount = 0;
        using (DjvuDocument document = DjvuNet.Tests.Util.GetTestDocument(index, out pageCount))
        {
            DjvuNet.Tests.Util.VerifyDjvuDocument(pageCount, document);
            DjvuNet.Tests.Util.VerifyDjvuDocumentCtor(pageCount, document);

            // DirmChunk is present only in multi page documents
            // in which root form is of DjvmChunk type
            if (document.RootForm.ChunkType == ChunkType.Djvm)
            {
                DirmChunk dirm = ((DjvmChunk)document.RootForm).Dirm;

                Assert.NotNull(dirm);

                Assert.True(dirm.IsBundled ? doc.Data.Dirm.DocumentType == "bundled" : doc.Data.Dirm.DocumentType == "indirect");

                var components = dirm.Components;
                Assert.Equal<int>(components.Count, doc.Data.Dirm.FileCount);
            }
        }
    }
```

One of the theory function arguments is not serializable in xUnit but despite that theory tests will be displayed individually and numbered. If first argument to theory function is of the string type it will be used as a name of the test besides being an argument to function invocation.

Credit for the idea goes to other developer - I have to find a link to his code - but it was reimplemented from scratch for DjvuNet project.

Answer (score 0):

A very silly solution that works nonetheless with very little extra code - have only one test input - a string that you want to be displayed in test explorer. And have some way to fetch actual test data by that string - can be a dictionary, a method, whatever works best in your case.

For example:

```cs
private (string someTestData, int someTestValue, string expectedResult) GetTestSomethingTestCaseData(string testCase)
{
    return testCase switch
    {
        "when it's A" => ("A data", 10, "A data 10"),
        "when it's B" => ("B data", 20, "B data 20"),
        _ => throw new ArgumentException(nameof(testCase))
    };
}


[Theory(DisplayName = "Test something")]
[InlineData("when it's A")]
[InlineData("when it's B")]
public void TestSomething(string testCase)
{
    var (someTestData, someTestValue, expectedResult) = GetTestSomethingTestCaseData(testCase);

    var actualResult = $"{someTestData} {someTestValue}";

    Assert.Equal(expectedResult, actualResult);
}
```